# meteorjs environment, getting element by id return strange value

Tags: events, meteor

I'm collaborating in a Meteorjs app, in wich i'm at first tries.
I builded some very simple templates to fit my needs.

In my code it happens that i have to check the value of a input text.
So i setup an event on that text box.

this is the text input:

```
<input type="text" name="meName" id="mockupName" />
<input type="button" {{buttonDisabled}} id="mockupCreate" value="New Mockup" />
```

The event check the text value and disable or enable the button. Very straight forward.

this is the event:

```
  'keydown #mockupName': function(e) {
    if (e.target.value.trim() == '') {
      Session.set('buttonDisabled','disabled');
    } else {
      Session.set('buttonDisabled','');
    }
  },
```

It works just ok.

e.target has a reference to my text input, and value store its value.

Now i referenced this template from another page, in a big template i wrote:

```
{{#if mockupSelected}}
  <input type="button" id="sw_product" value="switch to product view" />
  {{> mockupEditor}}
{{else}}
  Select product from the left
{{/if}}
```

And actually when mockupSelected returns true my template appears.

**The event is not working anymore.**

When the event fire ( and it fires ) i do a `console.log(e.target)`

Before i was getting: `<input#mockupName>` a reference to my input.
Now i m getting: `Object { __impl4cf1e782hg__: <input#mockupName>, parentNode_: undefined, firstChild_: undefined, lastChild_: undefined, nextSibling_: undefined, previousSibling_: undefined, treeScope_: Object }`

An object with a series of properties, one of which contains my reference.

This is the list of meteor packages installed:

```
meteor-platform
natestrauser:cart
http
iron:router
accounts-base
accounts-password
accounts-ui
alanning:roles
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
twbs:bootstrap
jeremy:velocity-animate
ajduke:bootstrap-tokenfield
sergeyt:typeahead
standard-app-packages
babrahams:editable-text-wysiwyg-bootstrap-3
differential:vulcanize
dburles:collection-helpers
fortawesome:fontawesome
yogiben:admin
```

I would like to know how i can access to that text input, considering that i do not know that key and that getElementById is returning me the same object.

I could iterate over all the object properties and testing if one of the values is actually a nodeElement of type text, but i do not think this is a solution.

Can anyone tell me how to get back to the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but have you tried:

.html

```
<input type="text" name="meName" id="mockupName" class="mockupName" />
<input type="button" {{buttonDisabled}} id="mockupCreate" value="New Mockup" />
```

.js

```
  'keydown .mockupName': function(e) {
    if (e.target.value.trim() == '') {
      Session.set('buttonDisabled','disabled');
    } else {
      Session.set('buttonDisabled','');
    }
  },
```

either that, or try changing the name of the control (mockupname -> uniqueMockupName). I had strange behaviour once when there were duplicate field names.

Comment: mmm i can even try, but the id is unique. Also selecting by class will give me unexpected result once i apply that class somewhere else.